# Is there any way to rename the Facebook "Send" Button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, button

Is there any way to rename the [Facebook "Send" Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/)?

From a UX view it's wrong, the button should be called "Send..." anyway. It would be even nicer to give it your own name. "Send invites..." for example.

Didn't find a way to rename it though. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option to change the text on the "Send" button.

You can hovewer use [Send Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) with your custom button...

BTW, for invites you should be using Facebook Requests with [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) (at least that's what suggested on Developers documentation)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I looked a the FB Send Dialog too, but it's not really an alternative. I just want(ed) to rename the button.
We went with FB Request first, but these are really not useful. The tracking needs quite some time and if a friend of mine was on the iPhone, the request (notification) was marked as read but not shown.

Comment: Okay, actually it's probably the best way to go! Thanks for your help.